How to get currently ringing number in Android without Call Screening Permission?
I'm building an appointment app for a client. One of the features is to tap a button in the app to get the phone number of the call going in the background. It works fine in devices below Android 10. However, after Android 10, you can only get the last completed call, and not the current one (unless you take on the CallScreening role, which is a lot of permission to ask for an appointment app).
What would you recommend in this situation? I've thought of the following:

Reading number from the Notification. But every calling app will display it differently, so it's not ideal.
Waiting till the call ends and then fetching the number. This essentially sidesteps the issue but maybe is the best we can do?


U cant get that

My suggestion would be to just ask the user for their phone number. The reason is, this is an appointment app. People are not expecting surprises.
If they have never given you the number by typing it, then they're also not expected to get a call or txt message from you later.
Follow how everybody else is doing, ask for the phone number and send a txt message for a code.
